# read new message top on listview

Tags: android, list, view

I'm trying crate a chat app.
Users can write and read but when a user writes message it's going to the bottom of the list.. I want to reverse. I want to  new message go top on list.

I try several ways 2 days.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Firebase mFirebaseRef;
    FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> mListAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://hkhkhh.firebaseio.com");

        final EditText textEdit = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.text_edit);
        Button sendButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.send_button);



        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = textEdit.getText().toString();
                Map<String,Object> values = new HashMap<>();
                values.put("name", "Android User");
                values.put("text", text);
                mFirebaseRef.push().setValue(values);
                textEdit.setText("");
            }
        });



        final ListView listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        mListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this, ChatMessage.class,

                android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, mFirebaseRef) {

            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
                ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(model.getName());
                ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(model.getText());

            }
        };

        listView.setAdapter(mListAdapter);


    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mListAdapter.cleanup();
    }
}
```

and
chatmessage java

```
package com.ankayapim.ozan.kagit23;

public class ChatMessage {
    private String name;
    private String text;



    public ChatMessage() {
        // necessary for Firebase's deserializer
    }
    public ChatMessage(String name, String text) {
        this.name = name;
        this.text = text;
    }



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your `ChatMessage` as your objects for arraylist and mFirebaseRef as your adapter list. you should add new message to arraylist.

```
ChatMessage newmsg = new ChatMessage();
//give text to newmsg 

mFirebaseRef.add(0,newmsg);


mListAdapter .addAll(mFirebaseRef);
```

create a public method addAll on your adapter class.

```
public void addAll(ArrayList<ChatMessage> data) {


        try {
            if (data != null){
                this.mData.clear();
                this.mData.addAll(data);
            }

            else this.mData = new ArrayList<>()

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

call  `notifyDataSetChanged();`